# Generating customized efi.img file from GRUB SOURCE

Tags: grub2, bootloader, grub-efi

I have booted my system with Ubuntu 18.04 ISO Image.  The system is up and running fine.

Towards changing the GRUB bootloader, I have followed below steps:

Mounted the 18.04 ISO image on the Ubutu system using below command.
*sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-18.04_Image.iso.iso ~/mount_point*

Copied the contents of ISO mount point to local colder “Ubuntu”.
*sudo cp -rf ~/mount_point ~/ubuntu*

Now the contents of the grub folder from ISO image is as below:

**-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2523136 Feb  9 23:31 efi.img**

-r--r--r-- 1 root root    5004 Feb  8 04:50 font.pf2

-r--r--r-- 1 root root     941 Feb 10 05:57 grub.cfg

-r--r--r-- 1 root root     604 Feb 10 05:57 loopback.cfg

dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root   32768 Feb  9 23:31 x86_64-efi/

I need to modify/customize the grub bootloader.

My goal is to generate efi.img file from the GRUB source code, copy it to ISO  image folder i.e) ~/mount_point/ubuntu/boot/grub, create my ISO image and boot the system.

Towards this I have follow below steps
Downloaded the GRUB source from “git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/grub.git”

Compiled the GRUB source code as below:
./bootstrap
./configure
make

Question 1:  After compilation I do not have efi.img file generated.  How do I generate efi.img file?

Here, my understanding is that if I can generate efi.img file, copy it back to ISO dump folder ~/ubuntu generate an .iso image, so that my bootloader modifications are visible.

Question 2:  Is this my understanding correct?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards

Srinivasa

Comment: Late to the party, but I am facing the same challenge: the older "efi.img" I have been including for the last several years gives issues when attempting to boot EFI-only hardware. I don't understand how newer Ubuntu ISOs work as they don't include an efi.img